# Inapproriate content to title

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, close-reasons, delete

Recently this old question came to my notice because of a downvote:

[Do magnets redshift light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/114982/do-magnets-redshift-light)

The content of the question is all about a hypothetical experiment full of unphysical hypotheseis:

glaring unphysical ones:

> the smaller paramagnetic material (Titanium Brick) is somehow converted into photons

> These photons are shot upwards via an perfect mirror perpendicular to the paramagnetic material above.

> When they reach the magnet's original position they are again converted into mass in the form of the titanium brick.

I flagged the question to be deleted, because the answers do not correspond to the title, and the content of the question  is science fiction, so search engines will be coming up with no sense answers.

For some reason the flag was *Your recent flag was declined - please review it before flagging this post!* .

I thought one of the  aims of physics.se is about questions and answers on mainstream physics to be available for search engines.

Answer (score 9):

When you actually review your flag, you should see the following reason for it being declined:

> declined - Please vote to close the question normally if you think it is off-topic here.

Moderators do not delete questions just because one user flags them to be deleted, and we do not *delete* questions just for being off-topic anyway. Questions that are off-topic should be *closed*. If you think this question is inappropriate for our site, just vote for it to be closed.

Comment: This response saddens me, because I have seen moderators (one person only)  closing inappropriate questions,  as this question is being left open. I must have a higher opinion for the aims of this site than it deserves.

Comment: @annav Unilateral closures typically happen on *new* questions with no answers. This question is from '14, is highly upvoted and as several answers. You *yourself* answered it in '14 instead of closing it! If the community now decides this question is off-topic for the site as we understand it today, that's fine by me, but I don't feel it would be appropriate for me (or any other moderator) to close it unilaterally.